# How to detect when user does not click on a layer? Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am using leafletjs in a project. On the map I have several polygons and markers. There is a click event on all of them to display some information when one of them is clicked. I would like to take the information away if the user clicks on a 'blank' part of the map (not on any polygons or markers). I know the map has the 'click' event but so far I am struggling to find a way to detect if the user clicked on a layer. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preclick` event to clear all the data
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-preclick